# Ocaml #load without top level?

Tags: ocaml

I have a problem with ocaml, i'm a beginner in ocaml.
I want to use #load "....ml" .
Then open "....ml" .

When I'm using emacs it's ok but I currently using linux xfce with ocaml compiler and when I try to use #load and open, I have a syntax error.

I have already look on the web, if I didn't need to use '#' before load but I have also a syntax error.

Example of my code which work with Emacs :

```
#load "list_ap1.cmo"
open List_ap1;;
```

And there is what is it in liste_ap1.cmo

```
module List_ap1 =
  struct
    let len(l) = List.length l;;

let fst(l) =
  match l with
    [] -> failwith "error empty list"
  | hd::tail -> hd
;;
```

Can anyone help me ? 
Have a nice day

Comment: could you please better describe your use case with some example ?

Comment: Maybe add a small sample of actual code to your question? Just enough to show that it works in Emacs, but not in your other environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned in [toplevel](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/toplevel.html), `#load` is for loading a bytecode file, which means that you have already compiled a ocaml source to bytecode using `ocamlc`, and in that case, you will load a file with extension `.cmo` or `.cma`. The leading `#` means that it is a command meant for the toplevel environment, and it is not a ocaml keyword.

`open` is a keyword to open a ocaml module (see [modules](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/modules.fr.html)) meant for structuring ocaml code.

To launch an ocaml toplevel environment, and not the compiler, just launch : `ocaml` , you will be able to invoke `#load`.
Once `List_ap1` is loaded, you can use its function by writing the full path : `List_ap1.len` . Or if you `open` this module, you name directly the function without the module name as prefix.

Comment: Thanx for answering.
And is there some alternative to # ? For this use

Comment: in fact, what is unclear is what you intend to do exactly, I fail to catch your use case. Are you looking for interpreting an ocaml source file in an ocaml code ? This is not possible.

Comment: Indeed it's a school lesson about list in Ocaml.
And normaly we should use emacs with tuareg but I'm using xfce and I compile my code with ocamlc, so in this exercise, the teacher has give us a .cmo file with a module in this .cmo file and we need to use this file.

Comment: ok - in your course you are using ocaml toplevel wrapped in emacs thx to tuareg. You can do the same by running ocaml (without the c). Just launch ocaml and you have a toplevel environment with the commands like #load. And if you want a better toplevel, install utop - it is top !